# Enemy don not follow Player. Phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Can you please tell me where I made mistake in code ? why my enemy do not follow player?
I am not sure if I defined correct followPlayer() .
'SceneB' is second Scene, can be this problem ?  Console.log is clear . I am using EasyStar.js library. Game is working , everything is running but enemy is frozen .
Thank you

```
 class SceneB extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
      super('SceneB')
    }
   //..


create(){

finder = new EasyStar.js()
    let grid = []
    let tile 
    for(let y = 0; y < map.height; y++) {
         let col = []
      for(let x = 0; x < map.width; x++) {
         tile = map.getTileAt( x, y )
         col.push( tile.index)
      }
      grid.push(col)
    }

    finder.setGrid(grid)
  
    let tileset = map.tilesets[0]
    let properties = tileset.tileProperties
    let acceptableTiles = []

    for (let i = tileset.firsgid - 1;i < tiles.total;i++) {
       if(properties[i].collides == false ) {
         acceptableTiles.push ( i+1)
       }
    }

       finder.setAcceptableTiles( acceptableTiles) 

}


update(){}

followPlayer(player,evil) {
      

      let toX = this.player.x
      let toY = this.player.y

      let fromX = this.evil.x
      let fromY = this.evil.y

      finder.findPath(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, function(path) {
         console.log(path)
         this.moveCharacter(path)
       })

       finder.calculate()
    }


      moveCharacter(path){
        let mytimeline = this.scene.tweens.createTimeLine()    

        for(let i = 0;i < path.length - 1;i++) {
          let ex = path[i + 1].x
          let ey = path[e + 1].y

            mytimeline.add({
             targets: this.player,
            x:{value: ex * map.tileWidth, duration: 200},
            y:{value: ey * map.tileHeight, duration: 200}
          })
        }
        mytimeline.play()
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`followPlayer` is never getting called, so the logic will never actually trigger.

You'll want to call this somewhere in your code, depending upon how you've implemented your `player` logic.

You may also want to check inside `finder.findPath` that `path !== null`, and do something if it is, as that could also cause an issue.

```js
finder.findPath(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, function(path) {
 console.log(path);
 if (path !== null) {
     this.moveCharacter(path);
 }
});
```